# terrain lighting issue Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, graphics, shader

I'm getting some weird effect on my terrain on iOS devices. In editor, it looks fine; on device it shows the light like the image below. The textures on the terrain are using the built in standard. I have verified that the metallic property is set to 0. I have Tried changing the material, the probes, all are not fixing the issue. Looking to see if anyone has experienced a similar issue or have a lead; I can work on a test. Using unity 5.3.5p5

[image]

Comment: Is the lighting baked or real time? If baked maybe play around with the bake settings. If not ask on Unity Answers, the devs are quite active there.

Comment: the problem is the terrain itself - it's old, never updated thing with many problems such as optimization. It's better not to use it, but I think it's not the answer.

Comment: Kind of reminds me of the so called "shadow acne artifacts" from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416324(v=vs.85).aspx
Could you tinker your bias value to see if provides any improvement?

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt open this image but to my understanding you have a problem with terrain material.There is a several ways to solve this problem

1-) Be sure click the "Static" box on inspector window.

2-) Increase "Pixel light count" from Edit > Project Settings > Quality in normal time that variable is be arranged to 4 but I prefer 8 or 10 test it.

3-)Be sure about lights.Look their lighting Mode Realtime,Mixed and Baked They should be same for great scenes

After this tips if you scene is still broken delete terrain material and create a new terrain material.Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If it's fine in editor then it might be an issue with your builds. Might try checking your quality settings to see if there are some lighting or shadow settings turned down. Go to Edit->Project settings->Quality and make sure the settings you have under the quality level and quality settings look appropriate for you build target (ios).